# Eclipse: unable to change proxy authentication information for Luna on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to update my network proxy settings on Luna but they are not taking .  I used the manual option and enter auth information. When I close the window, the settings are not there.  How can I correct this issue?

This is Eclipse Luna for Mac, OSX Yosemite.

Here is the error

> java.lang.SecurityException: Could not obtain password.  Result:
>   -25300    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.osx.OSXProvider.getPassword(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.osx.OSXProvider.getPassword(OSXProvider.java:45)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.PasswordProviderModuleExt.getPassword(PasswordProviderModuleExt.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.getModulePassword(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:259)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.getPassword(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:224)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.put(SecurePreferences.java:224)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesWrapper.put(SecurePreferencesWrapper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.saveProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:550)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.setProxyData(ProxyType.java:154)

I was considering 'clearing the passwords' in secure storage?  I have never done this before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should first try cleaning `SOCKS` from `Eclipse`. Do that by the following -
Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.

Now remove the proxy bypass and clear SOCKS IP.

**NOTE:- This will work if your have proxy server.**

Now go ahead and set your `Active Provider` to `Manual` mode. Do this by -

- Open Network Connection Settings.
- Select Active Provider to "Manual".
- Set HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

Restart `Eclipse` to apply these settings.

Your problem should now be solved.

Comment: I added 'Clear Passwords' from the security configuration.